# How do I extract all subjects of a cacertfile with the openssl command line?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Is there an openssl command to extract all certifacte subjects of a cacertfile (a file containing several certificates like /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt)?

I tried `openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -noout -subject` but it only gives me the subject of the first certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe OpenSSL can do that. OpenSSL assumes one cert per file for x509 actions.

According to [this site](http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/general.shtml#multi) you have to split them into individual files. He even provides [a perl script](http://gagravarr.org/code/cert-split.pl) that will split it for you. You could then loop over the files, or modify the perl script to extract the subject directly.

Answer (score 6):

To print all subjects within CA file:

`openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile ca-certificates.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout | grep 'Subject:'`

Comment: Small variation to get it in "distinguished name (DN)" format: `openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile ca-certificates.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout | grep subject`

Answer (score 2):

Set the `file` variable to point to your file, modify openssl command and you are good to go:

```
file="your file name"; first=""; for i in $(grep -n CERT "${file}" | cut -f 1 -d:)
do
    if [ -z "$first" ]
    then
        first=$i
        continue
    fi
    sed -n "$first,${i}p" "${file}" | openssl x509 -noout -subject
    first=""
done
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding a description of how the commands work.  And BTW, you don't need the curly braces in `${file}`.

Comment: this script works exactly as expected, it takes each certificate section out of a (chain) file and shows the subject lines