# List all available ssl ca certificates

Tags: linux, openssl

My git client claims

```
error: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
```

That means it can not find the corresponding ssl server key in the global system keyring. I want to check this by looking at the **list of all system wide available ssl keys** on a gentoo linux system. How can I get this list?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

It's not SSL keys you want, it's certificate authorities, and more precisely their certificates.

You could try:

```
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
    /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

To get the "subject" of every CA certificate in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` (this works because `openssl` exits after reading an individual cert block, but `awk` relaunches `openssl` on the next `print | cmd` call).

Beware that sometimes, you get that error when SSL servers forget to provide the intermediate certificates.

Use `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect the-git-server:443` to get the list of certificates  being sent.

Note that the pathname of the certificates bundle may differ depending on operating system. The directory holding the `certs` sub-directory is given by the command `openssl version -d`. The actual certificates file in that directory may additionally have a different name.

Comment: // , This does not work on CEntOS 6, but I have added an answer for CEntOS 6 here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363309/48498

Comment: The list from `trust list` from [p11-kit package](http://p11-glue.freedesktop.org/p11-kit.html) is essentially the same?

Comment: I just posted a [bash version of this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/614502/27653)

Comment: @F.Hauri, The command I gave should work in `bash` or any shell of the Bourne, rc, or fish families. If put on one line, it would work in any shell that I know, even csh, even the Unix V6 shell.

Comment: I agree, your solution is correct and efficient, I've just posted an alternative, using bash's arrays and some pretty output formatting, showing some usefull bash features

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, works great on Debian, thanks. Could you please provide a breakdown in your answer of what that first command line instruction to read the CA cert subject is actually doing?

Comment: @JonasStein (Re: your edit suggestion) while it's true `openssl` exits upon seeing the `END CERTIFICATE`, it would still work even if it didn't as we `close(cmd)` which closes the pipe to `openssl`  and waits for the corresponding process to exit upon the next `BEGIN` upon which `openssl` would see EOF and exit. Try with `cmd=wc` instead for instance.

Comment: The `openssl s_client` tip to get the exact list of certs a server is sending is super useful (ran into an issue where a misconfigured server was only sending its leaf cert instead of the full chain. Browsers compensate for that, but most other SSL/TLS client libraries don't)

Comment: That's one interesting way to use `awk`.

Answer (score 37):

Not sure about Gentoo but most distros put their certificates soft-link in system-wide location at `/etc/ssl/certs`.

- Key files go into `/etc/ssl/private`
- System-provided actual files are located at `/usr/share/ca-certificates`
- Custom certificates go into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`

Whenever you put a certificate in one of the above mentioned paths, run `update-ca-certificates` to update `/etc/ssl/certs` lists.

Comment: `/etc/ssl/certs` is the correct folder in gentoo. But the files are not well to read for human eyes.

Comment: It's `update-ca-certificates` with an additional `s` (can't edit this myself, as it's just a one-character edit).

Comment: @SlavenRezic - Someone fixed it.

Comment: sudo update-ca-certificates --verbose --fresh

Answer (score 6):

I had a requirement to list all the certs on our server and notify if they are due to expire.  We came up with this command:

```
locate .pem | grep "\.pem$" | xargs -I{} openssl x509 -issuer -enddate -noout -in {}
```

Comment: Note that openssl x509 format expects only a single cert in a pem file. Multiple certs if present need to follow some parsing given  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17744/how-do-i-extract-all-subjects-of-a-cacertfile-with-the-openssl-command-line

Answer (score 4):

A quick way to list all currently trusted CA certificates by openssl (with Ubuntu default directories):

```
find /etc/ssl/certs -type l -iname "*.0" -exec cat "{}" \; | awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject -enddate 2>/dev/null | tr "\n" " " ; echo' '/BEGIN/{cert=""};{cert=sprintf("%s\n%s",cert,$0)};/END/{print cert | cmd ;close(cmd)}' | sed -r 's:^subject=::' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one it this one:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout | grep subject
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times, when examining ca certificates, you will want (and  should) grep with `fingerprint`. You can also pass the output to `less` for searching/matching manually.
In general verifying the certificate fingerprint rather than just its name/issuer name/date e.t.c is very important.

```bash
# By piping to less you can manually search by hitting '/'
cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | keytool -printcert 2>/dev/null | 
grep "^Certificate\[" -A11 | less
```

**Output:**

```
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=ES, O=ACCV, OU=PKIACCV, CN=ACCVRAIZ1
Issuer: C=ES, O=ACCV, OU=PKIACCV, CN=ACCVRAIZ1
Serial number: 5ec3b7a6437fa4e0
Valid from: Thu May 05 12:37:37 EEST 2011 until: Tue Dec 31 11:37:37 EET 2030
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 93:05:7A:88:15:C6:4F:CE:88:2F:FA:91:16:52:28:78:BC:53:64:17
         SHA256: 9A:6E:C0:12:E1:A7:DA:9D:BE:34:19:4D:47:8A:D7:C0:DB:18:22:FB:07:1D:F1:29:81:49:6E:D1:04:38:41:13
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA (weak)
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 4096-bit RSA key
Version: 3

--
Certificate[2]:
Owner: OU=AC RAIZ FNMT-RCM, O=FNMT-RCM, C=ES
Issuer: OU=AC RAIZ FNMT-RCM, O=FNMT-RCM, C=ES
Serial number: 5d938d306736c8061d1ac754846907
Valid from: Wed Oct 29 17:59:56 EET 2008 until: Tue Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 2030
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: EC:50:35:07:B2:15:C4:95:62:19:E2:A8:9A:5B:42:99:2C:4C:2C:20
         SHA256: EB:C5:57:0C:29:01:8C:4D:67:B1:AA:12:7B:AF:12:F7:03:B4:61:1E:BC:17:B7:DA:B5:57:38:94:17:9B:93:FA
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 4096-bit RSA key
Version: 3

--
....
....
```

And since the above command prints also a sequential number for each certificate (`e.g. Certificate[3]`) you can then pick the actual certificate with:

```bash
# Let's say you want to pick certificate number 3
awk -v n=3 '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/ && ++k == n, /END CERTIFICATE/' /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

**Output:**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

### openssl and pure bash way

Even if [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97252/27653), work fine and is efficient, I would like to post this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script who will give near same result, but don't use `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec {sslout}<> <(:)
cnt=1
while read -u $certs line; do
    [ "$line" ] && case $line in 
        *BEGIN*)
            exec {ssl}> >(openssl x509 -noout -subject >&${sslout})
            echo $line 1>&$ssl
        ;;
        *END*)
            echo $line 1>&$ssl
            exec {ssl}>&-
            read -u $sslout subject
            printf "%03d  %s\n" $((cnt++)) "${subject#subject=}"
        ;;
        *)
            echo $line 1>&$ssl
        ;;
    esac;
done {certs}< /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
exec {certs}>&- {sslout}>&-
```

### One step further

Searching for certs in all dirs mentionned by [SHW's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97249/27653), sorting by *hashes* and count

```
#!/bin/bash

exec {sslout}<> <(:)
cnt=0
hashed=()
while read -u $certs line; do
    [ "$line" ] && case $line in 
        *BEGIN*)
            exec {ssl}> >(openssl x509 -noout -hash -subject >&${sslout})
            echo $line 1>&$ssl
        ;;
        *END*)
            echo $line 1>&$ssl
            exec {ssl}>&-
            read -u $sslout hash
            read -u $sslout subject
            ((cnt++))
        hashed[16#$hash]+="${subject#subject=}"$'\t'
        ;;
        *)
            echo $line 1>&$ssl
        ;;
    esac
done {certs}< <(find /etc/ssl/certs /usr/{local/,}share/ca-certificates \
                    -type f -exec cat {} +)
exec {certs}>&- {sslout}>&-
echo "$cnt certs read, ${#hashed[@]} different hashes."
for i in ${!hashed[@]};do
    IFS=$'\t' read -a subj <<<"${hashed[i]}"
    printf "%8x  %s\n" $i "$subj"
    ((${#subj}>1)) && printf "          %s\n" "${subj[@]:1}"
done
```

may output something like:

```
    256 certs read, 128 different hashes.
 3179a64  C = NL, O = Staat der Nederlanden, CN = Staat der Nederlanden EV Root CA
          C = NL, O = Staat der Nederlanden, CN = Staat der Nederlanden EV Root CA
 62cdee6  OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
          OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
 64e0aa9  C = BM, O = QuoVadis Limited, CN = QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3
          C = BM, O = QuoVadis Limited, CN = QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Find with crt or key files shall also work

```
find / -type f -name *.key
find / -type f -name *.crt
```

Comment: Not the efficient approach..

Comment: Would also find files that are *not* available system-wide, and care needs to be taken to avoid premature expansion of the wildcards.