# How do I list all available SSL CA certificates on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, ssl, certificates

It's difficult to tell whether I've succeeded in trusting a given certificate, after I have installed it, especially for root CAs.

To check whether I have successfully installed a certificate without making an SSL request to a server that may or may not provide it, I would like to **list of all system wide available ssl certificates**.

I followed the instructions here, and they worked:

https://serverfault.com/questions/559571/install-a-root-certificate-in-centos-6

Also, this asks a similar question, but gives an answer for gentoo systems:

[List all available ssl ca certificates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97244/list-all-available-ssl-ca-certificates)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

// , Use the `openssl` command to get output from `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Anyway, I tried the following, mostly copied from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97249/48498, and it seemed to work if I changed the filename to account for CentOS 6:

If you don't want to have to bother with the `--insecure` flag or its analogues on cURL, `wget`, Git, etc, you can add a CA root certificate, self-signed certificate, or certificate chain to your trust store as follows:

1.
Follow the instructions to download the `.crt`, `.pem`, or `.cer` of your choice.

2.
Obtain the certificate you want to trust through whatever mechanism you use, often by downloading it from a central repository or by extracting it from an SSL handshake with `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect some.host.that.uses.that.root:443`, or such, and copy it to the following folder on the target CentOS 6 host:

```
    /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
```

3. 

Run the following commands while logged in to the target host:

```
    $ sudo update-ca-trust enable; sudo update-ca-trust extract
```

4. 

**Verify the results on the Red Hat based OS**, e.g.:

```
    $ awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
        /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

This should yield a long list of responses of the form:

```
    subject= /C=US/O=MyCorp/CN=root-ca-2048
```

Step #4 in the above answers this question, and the other steps provide context for the unwary.