# Does my system accept the new let's encrypt root certificate?

Tags: openssl, letsencrypt

Let's encrypt changes there root certificate from DST Root CA X3 to ISRG Root X1- how can I check if my server (which connects to an api with let's encrypt certificate) works still in future?

Answer (score 0):

The let's encrypt certificate chain will be different in future, see [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/), [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/openssl-client-compatibility-changes-for-let-s-encrypt-certificates/143816) and [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/).

Problem may be older systems like ubuntu 16.04 without updates. If you want to be safe, just run this line to see if the new root certificate is installed:

```
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
    /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | grep ISRG
```

As an idea by: [List all available ssl ca certificates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97244/list-all-available-ssl-ca-certificates)